# ruby on rails manys' many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many

I am wondering how to do this without double each loop.
Assume that I have a user model and order model, and user has_many orders.

Now I have a users array which class is User::ActiveRecord_Relation

How can I get the orders of these users in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the best way to do that is :

```
users.includes(:orders).map(&:orders)
```

Cause you eager load the orders of the users (only 2 sql queries)

Or

```
Order.where(user_id: users.pluck(:id))
```

is quite good too in term of performance

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a many-to-many association and you need to quickly load in all the associated orders you will need to be careful to avoid the so-called "N plus 1" load that can result from the most obvious approach:

```
orders = users.collect(&:orders).flatten
```

This will iterate over each user and run a query like `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id=?` without any grouping.

What you really want is this:

```
orders = Order.where(user_id: users.collect(&:id))
```

That should find all orders from all users in a single query.

Comment: Thank you both! I would mark Oxynum answer as answer for give new guy an encouragement if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

An answer just come up my mind after I asked....

```
users.map {|user| user.orders}
```

Comment: Shorter: `users.map(&:orders)`.